# displays only 1 data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I tried to query data, but the data is more than 1. I want to display only 1 data, which is the first data.

Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.country_id,
                a.street_address,
                a.city,
                a.phone_number,
                a.location_id,
                b.ket
  FROM LOCATIONS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT y.country_id,
                                   y.country_name || ' ' || z.REGION_NAME AS ket
                     FROM countries y, regions z
                    WHERE y.REGION_ID = z.REGION_ID) b
    ON a.country_id = b.country_id;
```

[image]

Comment: "first" with regard to _which_ column(s)?  Can you add sample data to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic function such as `DENSE_RANK()` including ordering by `country_id` (presuming the ordering column from the image) in order to bring the first row(including ties) such as

```
SELECT country_id, street_address, city, phone_number, location_id, ket
  FROM
  (
    SELECT l.country_id,
           l.street_address,
           l.city,
           l.phone_number,
           l.location_id,
           c.country_name || ' ' || r.region_name AS ket,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY l.country_id) AS dr
      FROM locations l
      LEFT JOIN countries c
        ON l.country_id = c.country_id
      LEFT JOIN regions r
        ON c.region_id = r.region_id
    )
  WHERE dr = 1
```

Comment: You're welcome; deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get first row from your query please try this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.country_id, a.street_address, a.city, a.phone_number, a.location_id, b.ket FROM LOCATIONS a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT y.country_id, y.country_name || ' ' || z.REGION_NAME AS ket FROM countries y, regions z WHERE y.REGION_ID=z.REGION_ID) b ON a.country_id = b.country_id
order by a.country_id
    fetch first 1 rows only;
```

(I have added order by clause (assumed that you want the rows with first country). Without order by clause it's not guaranteed to have same rows every time.)

Comment: Without`order by` it will be indefinite row. I think it is always should be said in SQL answers, that there's no *Nth* record in table/result set without explicit`order by`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have changed my answer.

Comment: The version `11g` has no `fetch` clause.